# Git log shows wrong commit date

Tags: git

For some reason all my recent git commits are being comitted with the wrong date.

I made two commits yesterday and one commit today and they all shows up as being commited *16 days ago*. More specifically **Fri Oct 31 15:32:21 2014 +0100**.

Running `date` on my computer yields **Sun 16 Nov 2014 12:55:08 CET**, so my computers time is correct.

When pushing the repository to GitHub the problem persists.

**Update #1:**

The repository in question can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/codeaken/cloudserver)

The [file listing](https://github.com/codeaken/cloudserver) shows the commit being made, when this is written, **25 minutes ago**. Which is correct.

The [commit log](https://github.com/codeaken/cloudserver/commits/master) has the commits in the correct date but showing **authored 16 days ago**

**Update #2:**

OS:

```
Darwin Juno.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64.
```

GIT Version:

```
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

GIT environment variables:

```
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=@1414765941 +0100
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/index
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=codeaken
GIT_PREFIX=
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=<removed>
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an environment variable (like `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`) set when you do your comit, that date will be used (instead of the current one)

Try unsetting `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`.

`GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` is usually used within git command (like git filter-branch) to set commits in the past. See "[How do I make a Git commit in the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895453/6309)".

Regarding GitHub:

- The [file listing in GitHub](https://github.com/codeaken/cloudserver) is based on the [*commit* date, not the *author* date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/6309).
- The [commit log](https://github.com/codeaken/cloudserver/commits/master) displays the *author* date, not the commit date.

Comment: @codeaken ok, which what OS, what git version? Do you have any `GIT_...` environment variable?

Comment: I have update the question with the information you requested

Comment: I have not manually set that environment variable. Any idea on why it could have been set? And why is Github, even though this is set, display the correct commit time in certain parts of the site (see update #1)?

Comment: @codeaken No,Ido not knowwhy that variable was set. I just know that it would explain why the dates are wrong.