# Backdating git commits

Tags: git

I suffered a hard drive crash and lost a couple of project folders. These are personal projects and weren't hosted anywhere. I have a dozen compressed zip files of releases, but that's it.

Were I to start with the earliest version, how can I change the date of the commit to match the release date? My thinking is I could do this for each of the versions and have the commit date at least somewhat semblance of the development timeline/history.

Comment: I would generally advise you against muddling around with commit dates.  If something happened on a certain date, then let it stand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git commit --amend --no-edit --date="Fri Nov 6 20:00:00 2015 -0600"`

Comment: But this would only work for the latest commit, not for any coming before that.

Comment: You can add the past date.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895453/how-do-i-make-a-git-commit-in-the-past?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Is it possible to check if commits have been backdated? Looking at a project now which we need to see if developers have tampered with it to make it look like it was worked on consistently?