# How to make fake git commit date?

Tags: git, commit

I want to change my history.

Is it possible to change commit date or make new commit with outdated date?

I think only about system date changing.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895453/how-do-i-make-a-git-commit-in-the-past

Comment: **Not a dupe** - this question is about the last commit and the orig is about the retroactive history rewriting. Check also the answers!

Answer (score 44):

Use the `--date` option when you commit:

```
git commit --date "Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 +0100"
```

Here are the supported date formats:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_date_formats