# Github doesn't show the amended commit date

Tags: github, git-commit

I use this command to modify a commit date:

```
 git commit --date="5 day ago" -m "modifying date"
```

The following is the result of the command above:

```
 [main 0ab160a] modifying date
 Date: Tue May 9 18:59:29 2023 +0300
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

I then push the commit using this command:

```
 git push -f origin main
```

Result of pushing the commit:

```
 Enumerating objects: 5, done.
 Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 267 bytes | 89.00 KiB/s, done.
 Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
 To https://github.com/testings1404/Testings.git
 1282afa..0ab160a  main -> main
```

I checked the commit through github website and it doesn't show the new date 9th of may. It shows the it was committed few minutes ago:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the fact that there are `committer` and `author` dates in git commits, as e.g. these answers point out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3896112/21012339
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/454750/21012339

Comment: I found a tool called git-redate. It does the work for you